# Maven doesn't recognize parameter when containing "-"

Tags: java, maven

I was trying to test [this](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin) maven plugin on a simple spring-boot project. But I'm facing an issue with mojo parameters, when I use parameter containing a "-" along with goals it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ mvn clean install fabric8:build fabric8:resource \
> -Dfabric8.openshift.enableAutomaticTrigger=false \
> -Dfabric8.enricher.fmp-openshift-imageChangeTrigger.enrichAll=true
```

But when I put these parameters as system properties in project's `pom.xml`. They seem to be picked by maven plugin and work as they are supposed to do. I added this to pom like this:

```
  <properties>
    <fabric8.openshift.enableAutomaticTrigger>false</fabric8.openshift.enableAutomaticTrigger>
    <fabric8.enricher.fmp-openshift-imageChangeTrigger.enrichAll>true</fabric8.enricher.fmp-openshift-imageChangeTrigger.enrichAll>
  </properties>
```

I'm a big confused here. Can anyone please tell me why it's not working in former case? Is there some kind of naming convention for mojo parameters that we're supposed to follow?

Comment: I'd assume that's not a problem of Maven not recognizing the dash but the command line / shell interpreting it. Did you try surrounding it with quotes/double quotes?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to surround it with quotes? like this: `-D"fabric8.enricher.fmp-openshift-imageChangeTrigger.enrichAll=true"`

Comment: Try "-Dfabric8.enricher.fmp-openshift-imageChangeTrigger.enrichAll=true"

Comment: Try to run your maven from eclipse using M2E plugin and passing parameter goal as you want ?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ. Is there some alternative for IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use a workaround (seems to me a faster solution than debug maven) :

```
<properties>
   <f8.autoTrigger>your_default_here</f8.autoTrigger>
   <f8.enrichAll>your_other_default_here<f8.enrichAll>
   <fabric8.openshift.enableAutomaticTrigger>${f8.autoTrigger}</fabric8.openshift.enableAutomaticTrigger>
   <fabric8.enricher.fmp-openshift-imageChangeTrigger.enrichAll>${f8.enrichAll}</fabric8.enricher.fmp-openshift-imageChangeTrigger.enrichAll>
</properties>
```

And if you want to override your defaults you can invoke maven like :

```
$ mvn clean install fabric8:build fabric8:resource \
> -Df8.autoTrigger=false \
> -Df8.enrichAll=true
```

It is even shorter :)